# Xamarin MVVM, binding ListView item as command parameter

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I have a ListView populated from a viewmodel an I can now easily bind elements of the datatemplate to properties of the datasource items and send those properties to a command in the view model. However I imagine one should be able to send the entire source item. However when I send anything other than a string either the app crashes or the buttons are all disabled and don't seem to trigger the command. This OOP and xamarin newb would very much appreciate any pointers/help. I suspect it is just the syntax in the button, or in the command that I don't understand, what I have at the moment is:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:TestViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout  >
        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Term_id}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        <ListView x:Name="propListView"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleProperties}"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell x:Name="theItem" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Text="{Binding Agt_name}"
                              Command="{Binding BindingContext.doCheckin, Source={x:Reference Page}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding BindingContext.doCheckin, Source={x:Reference theItem}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                    />
                            <Label Text="{Binding MilesDistance, StringFormat='~{0:f2} mi.'},
                        Converter={ConvertToDouble}}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

...

```
using AgentApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AgentApp
{
    class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Property> simpleProperties;
        public ObservableCollection<Property> SimpleProperties { set { SetProperty(ref simpleProperties, value); } get { return simpleProperties; } }

        private Property selectedItem;
        public Property SelectedItem { get { return selectedItem; } set { SetProperty(ref selectedItem, value); } }

        public ICommand setSelection { private set; get; }
        public ICommand doCheckin { private set; get; }
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            var SimplePropertiesList = new List<Property>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Property prop = new Property();
                prop.Term_id = i.ToString();
                prop.Agt_name = "Prop " + i.ToString();
                prop.MilesDistance = (double)i * 2.5;
                SimplePropertiesList.Add(prop);
            }
            SimpleProperties = new ObservableCollection<Property>(SimplePropertiesList);

            /* for buttons:*/
            doCheckin = new Command<Property>(
                execute: (Property item) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("doCheckin() executes: " + item.Term_id);
                    SelectedItem = item;
                },
            canExecute: (Property item) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("doCheckin() canExecute return" + item.Term_id);
                return (SelectedItem != item); 
            }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

and of course

```
class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"{Binding .}"` to refer to the current item

Comment: @Jason, thanks for helping me out. Out of interest, is there a more explicit way? e.g "Self" or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I imagine one should be able to send the entire source item. However when I send anything other than a string either the app crashes or the buttons are all disabled and don't seem to trigger the command.

According to your description, you want to pass current item when you click button, am I right? if yes, as Jason said, modifying Button CommandParameter like this:

```
  <ListView
            x:Name="propListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleProperties}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.doCheckin, Source={x:Reference page27}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                Text="{Binding Agt_name}" />
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding MilesDistance}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

 doCheckin = new Command((e) =>
        {
            var item = (e as Property);
            Console.WriteLine("the property Term_id is {0} ", item.Term_id);
        });
```

By the way, the selecteditem need to implement INotifyPropertychanged to update data.

```
  private Property _selectedItem;
    public Property selectedItem 
    { 
        get { 
            return _selectedItem; 
        } 
        set { 
            _selectedItem=value;
            OnPropertyChanged("selectedItem");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Cherry-bu-msft, I came right.
I implement the OnPropertyChanged in the BaseViewModel class that this ViewModel extends. What I was also missing was calling `(doCheckin as Command).ChangeCanExecute();` where the underlying variables are changed.