# In a ListView how to send the clicked object back to the command in the view model - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Given the following `ListView`, I'd like to have a command that would send the clicked object, in this case the Address, back to a command in the view model - `SelectNewAddress` or `DeleteAddress`.

```xml
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10,15,10,15">
                <Label Text="Addresses" FontSize="22" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="0,0,0,7" TextColor="#404040" />
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="1"
                                        HeightRequest="200"
                                        SeparatorVisibility="None"
                                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                                        FlowItemsSource="{Binding AllAddresses}">
                        <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="popups:AddressItem">
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,35" Padding="0,0,0,15" x:Name="Item">
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                                Command="{Binding SelectNewAddress}" />
                                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding MainAddress}" 
                                                LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" 
                                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
                                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                FontSize="18"
                                                TextColor="{StaticResource CommonBlack}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}"  >
                                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                                Command="{Binding SelectNewAddress}"/>
                                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <StackLayout Padding="10,0,0,0">
                                            <flex:FlexButton Icon="check.png" 
                                                                WidthRequest="25" 
                                                                HeightRequest="25"
                                                                CornerRadius="18"
                                                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" 
                                                                ForegroundColor="{StaticResource CommonWhite}" 
                                                                HighlightBackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}"
                                                                HighlightForegroundColor="{StaticResource CommonWhite}"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource invertBoolConverter}}">
                                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding DeleteAddress} />
                                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <StackLayout Padding="10,0,0,0">
                                            <flex:FlexButton Icon="deleteCard.png" 
                                                                WidthRequest="25" 
                                                                HeightRequest="25"
                                                                CornerRadius="18"
                                                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WooopDarkGray}" 
                                                                ForegroundColor="{StaticResource CommonWhite}" 
                                                                HighlightBackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}"
                                                                HighlightForegroundColor="{StaticResource CommonWhite}"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                    </flv:FlowListView>
                </StackLayout>
```

The commands in the view model are the following:

```cs
        ...

        public ICommand SelectNewAddress { get; set; }
        public ICommand DeleteAddress { get; set; }

        ...

        public AddressSelectionViewModel()
        {
            DeleteAddress = new Command(DeleteAddressCommand);
            SelectNewAddress = new Command(SelectNewAddressCommand);
        }
        
        ...
        private void SelectNewAddressCommand(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = (AddressItem)obj;
                AddressHelper.UpdateAddress(item.DeliveryAddressLocation);
                UpdateAddresses();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO
            }
        }

        private void DeleteAddressCommand(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = (AddressItem)obj;
                AddressHelper.RemoveAddress(item.DeliveryAddressLocation);
                UpdateAddresses();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO
            }
        }
```

I want the `object obj` passed to `SelectNewAddressCommand` and  `DeleteAddressCommand` to be the address clicked on the `ListView`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin MVVM, binding ListView item as command parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428609/xamarin-mvvm-binding-listview-item-as-command-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you have included your view model as `DataType` and view as `Class` inside the `ContentPage`:

```xml
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:your.namespace.ViewModels"
x:DataType="pages:AddressSelectionViewModel"
x:Class="your.namespace.Views.AddressSelectionPage"
```

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="..."
             xmlns:x="..." 
             xmlns:flv="..." 
             xmlns:popups="..." 
             xmlns:flex="..." 
             xmlns:views="..." 
             xmlns:xct="..." 
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:your.namespace.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="pages:AddressSelectionViewModel"
             x:Class="your.namespace.Views.AddressSelectionPage"
             Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="..."
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="..."
             Shell.TabBarIsVisible="...">
```

Inside the top `Grid` element add property `x:Name="Item"` ("Item" is only used as an example, you can name it anything):

```xml
                    <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="1"
                                        HeightRequest="200"
                                        SeparatorVisibility="None"
                                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                                        FlowItemsSource="{Binding AllAddresses}">
                        <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="popups:AddressItem">
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,35" Padding="0,0,0,15" x:Name="Item"> <!-- Here -->
```

Then we change the `Command` and `CommandParameter` of the `TapGestureRecognizer` to the following:

```xml
<TapGestureRecognizer 
        Command="{Binding Path=SelectNewAddress, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type pages:AddressSelectionViewModel}}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}" />
```

```xml
<TapGestureRecognizer 
        Command="{Binding Path=DeleteAddress, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type pages:AddressSelectionViewModel}}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}" />
```

In the `Command` we specify the function as `Path`, then we clarify that the source of this function is inside the view model through `AncestoryType`. When inside a list view we cannot reference properties outside the object being iterated. Hence, we need to specify the desired source.

So now we are referencing the actual function. But we aren't sending the `object obj` as a parameter yet.

In the `CommandParameter` we have to pass the currently bound object with `Path` and `Source`. Note that in Source we are referencing has the name `Item` we defined as the `x:Name` of the `Grid` earlier.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the page has the viewmodel as its BindingContext. (If you are doing mvvm, you've already done this.)
2. Give `<flv:FlowListView` a name:

```xml
<flv:FlowListView x:Name="theListView" ... >
```

3. The item needs to refer to the command in the page's viewmodel. BindingContext propagates down through the hierarchy, so this is easily done relative to the listview name:

```xml
    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
         <TapGestureRecognizer 
              Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectNewAddress, Source={x:Reference theListView}}" ...
```

4. The item's BindingContext is the item model, so that is easily passed as a parameter:

```xml
         <TapGestureRecognizer 
              Command=... CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

NOTE: Differences between this and Wizard's answer:

- **`{Binding .}` is all that is needed to refer to the item itself.**
- Instead of using `RelativeSource`, which requires specifying a `Type`, my personal preference is to **name** a view, then refer to that name. I find this easier to read and to remember how to do.
- I left out all details that are not relevant to the question. The above steps are sufficient. (`x:DataType` commands are good for performance, so I am in no way suggesting not to do them. But that is a separate topic, IMHO.)

Comment: UPDATE: I discovered the question has been asked before. So I've voted to close the question. But I'll leave this answer here, as a succinct summary.